# Problem using fetch in React inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to node and react and I am trying to fetch some data and show it on my react page.  It's pretty simple.  I have an express server running on localhost:3001 and my react app is on localhost:3000.
I'm attempting to fetch data and then set that data to a state via a hook.  I can't seem to get the data on the react page or in the web developer console.  Is there a way I can see the data that is being fetched in the console?

Here is my React component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


function App() {

  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState("");
  console.log(weatherData);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:3001"
      );
      const data = await result.json();
      console.log("data", data);


      setWeatherData(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>The temprature is {weatherData}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my node server:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https = require("https");
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'jsx')


app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  const query = Chicago;


  const apiKey = "a valid key";
  const unit = "imperial";
  const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=" + apiKey + "&q=" + query + "&units=" + unit;


  https.get(url, (response) => {
    console.log("statusCode", res.statusCode);

    response.on("data", (d) => {
      const weatherData = (JSON.parse(d));
      console.log(weatherData);
      res.send(weatherData);

    });
  }).on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  })
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

The result I get is no data and these 2 errors in chrome dev tools console.

index.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

App.jsx:19 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `Content-Type` of data returned from the server.

Either you can use `res.setHeader` before sending response or `res.json()` to send json response

```
https.get(url, (response) => {
    console.log("statusCode", res.statusCode);

    response.on("data", (d) => {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(d);
      console.log(weatherData);
      res.json(weatherData); // use json response

    });
  }).on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there maybe an error occur in result.json().

Probably the request return html rather then json.

You can use postman or other tools to get the real response by 'localhost:3001' to clear where goes wrong.

Comment: For some reason the server sending an HTML page instead of the data according to Postman.

Answer (score 0):

const data = await result.json();

this line will occur a problem if result does not have valid json. 
 that's why you have encountered an error. catch that error and see the response